# how to set default c++ compiler in windows cygwin and mingw

Tags: windows, cygwin, mingw

I have both Cygwin and MinGW compilers installed on my windows machine. I am installing a package which requires the Cygwin compiler but when I type the install command in the command line, it by default picks up the MinGW compiler. How can I use Cygwin without uninstalling MinGW?

Answer (score 1):

Both Cygwin and Mingw can be installed simultaneously possibly with 2 different versions(although keeping same version of gcc from 2 different projects isn't a good choice).

Which will be your default depends on the path variable setting.
Your path variable is the one where OS looks to execute from a command shell.
Now if you want cygwin to be default then make its entry first in path variable and then enter the mingW path variable or vice versa.You may have to close the command prompt or sign out completely if you were using the mingw or cygwin earlier and changed the default to another compiler.This is because of caching used by windows.

Alternatively you can use the IDE environment to set the defaults. For ex, in codeblocks am using GNU GCC compiler which uses mingw and in vs code I configured it with Cygwin compiler.

But be advised whenever there is a shell execution ,path variable is the key player.

Answer (score 0):

Set the PATH in cygwin to not include Mingw directory.

Better also in general to have cygwin directories as first; this is the default implementation in `/etc/profile/`